# not getting data from server into textview in android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, textview

I want to settext the data from server, i got a response from server when i do debugging but its not setting the settext.when i run the code nothing seems to happen, its not showing server data into textview:
here is my java class:

```
public class PMAddPigeonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String url= "http://.........php";
    TextView commission;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pmadd_pigeon);

  commission=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.comm) ;


        getData();
}
private void getData() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(PMAddPigeonActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
           String name1 = collegeData.getString("commission");
            commission.setText(name1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );





        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       // commission.setText(""+name );
    }
```

config.java

```
public class Config {

    public static final String KEY_NAME = "commission";

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

my json output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "commission": 0.01
}
```

my xml:

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

                android:id="@+id/comm"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"

                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pedigreeupload"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dname"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dname" />
```

Comment: you can set text to textview only on UI thread. Are you sure your `onResponse` is called on UI thread?

Comment: try to Log or Toast your response first, if it is as expected? or else post your JSON response as well.

Comment: make sure the `collegeData.getString("commission")` returns proper text  which is to be displayed

Comment: ok i will try toast it first

Comment: @junaid..i already posted my json response

Comment: no, its not showing response in toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have no JSON array in your response, you need to change your response handling as followed.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
 String name1 = jsonObject.getString("commission");
 commission.setText(name1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
```